# Copy a image from a remote server via jquery or javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, copy

anyone knows a way how i can copy a image from a remote server in a local directory via jQuery or JavaScript?

via php copy or cURL its not allowed on my webspace.

best regards

Comment: What do you mean copy an image? You can refernce the image path directly.

Comment: because the images are relatively big, and i will shrink the images on my webspace.

Comment: You would need to load the image, get the image data and post it to a PHP script to save it.  Have a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/934012/get-image-data-in-javascript

Comment: What do you mean copy? That is what is confusing? You want to save it on your sever with JavaScript?

Comment: i load a image from a remote site e.g. <img src="remote/site/image.jpg" /> then i will save it on my webspace, after click a button (form)